# Setting up az cli, however I cannot connect due to max retries failed, target host refused the connection. How can I get past my proxy in Windows?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I've followed Microsoft's instructions for "[Proxy Blocks a Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-powershell)", which reads:

> (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials =
> [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

...however I'm still receiving the following error when attempting to do `az login` or `az extension add --name azure-devops`:

> Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aka.ms', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /azure-cli-extension-index-v1 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot
> connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x0448E9F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it',)))

I'm trying to connect to our company's Org on dev.azure.com.   I've searched and have not come across anything that helps.

Thanks - please let me know if there is more info that's needed.   I know the address & port of my proxy, (http/s://proxy.{env}.{org}.com:{PORT}), however I don't see a way to explicitly state this, or if it would even work.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

Refer

- [Work behind a proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#work-behind-a-proxy)
- [Working with Azure CLI behind SSL intercepting proxy server](https://blog.jhnr.ch/2018/05/16/working-with-azure-cli-behind-ssl-intercepting-proxy-server/)
- [How to configure proxies for the Azure libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-configure-proxy)

Depending on whether you use cmd or bash, set the `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable as below:

**CMD**:

```
rem Non-authenticated HTTP server:
set HTTP_PROXY=http://{proxy host}:{port}

rem Authenticated HTTP server:
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@{proxy host}:{port}

rem Non-authenticated HTTPS server:
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://{proxy host}:{port}

rem Authenticated HTTPS server:
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@{proxy host}:{port}
```

**Bash**:

```sh
# Non-authenticated HTTP server:
HTTP_PROXY=http://{proxy host}:{port}

# Authenticated HTTP server:
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@{proxy host}:{port}

# Non-authenticated HTTPS server:
HTTPS_PROXY=http://{proxy host}:{port}

# Authenticated HTTPS server:
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@{proxy host}:{port}
```

Comment: The below code of Non-authenticated method works for me.
`HTTPS_PROXY=http://some-proxy.com:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://some-proxy.com:8080`